# I was confused in the following declaration of f

Tags: c++

I was confused in the following declaration of f. Is f variable, if yes then what type of var? Thanks.

```
int main(){
    ios::fmtflags f;

    f = cout.flags();
}
```

Comment: It's of type `ios::fmtflags`, exactly as it would have been of type `int` if the line had read `int f`. This is *fundamental* syntax, and not really appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a variable of type `ios::fmtflags`